# Dynamically set value of onClientClick

Tags: asp.net

I have a DataGrid template that correctly outputs a picture of a phone in each of my rows. When the user clicks the phone, I would like to display the phone number to the user, either through an alert box or through a jquery dialog.

I currently have:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/Phone.jpg"
 ID="imgDist_Phone" 
 OnClientClick="
    alertPhoneNumber('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") %>')
 " />
```

Obviously this doesn't work because it outputs `<%# DataBinder` literally.

What is the best way to generate the onClick event dynamically, so that I don't have to postBack to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/Phone.jpg"
     ID="imgDist_Phone" 
     OnClientClick='<%# string.Format( "alertPhoneNumber( \"{0}\" );", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber") ) %>' />
```

Should be close on the syntax